# Can a Ba'al Kri'ah review the parshiot that he must lain on Tish'a B'Av?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, torah-reading, tisha-bav

I understand that we are not supposed to learn Torah, in general from afternoon of Erev Tish'a B'av until after chatzot of Tish'a B'av except for designated areas such as Eicha, Iyov, etc.

Does this prohibition apply to the Ba'al Kri'ah who needs to review the Torah reading that he must do on Tish'a B'Av itself?

Comment: Presumably it would be OK, as we're allowed to learn it during the reading, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're understating the facts when you say that "we are not supposed to learn Torah, in general from afternoon of Erev Tish'a B'av until after chatzot of Tish'a B'av": we're not allowed until nightfall. Source: [*Mishna B'rura* 554:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93_%D7%90).

But someone who will read the Torah, even the afternoon reading, is allowed to review it. Source: [*MB* 554:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93_%D7%93).

Comment: The same should apply to anyone (and to the Haftarot as well). Why should a _Chazan_ be permitted to study something others can't?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know. _MB_ does say "היינו חזן הקורא"; I haven't checked other _acharonim_.