# Learning Dikduk on Tish’ah B’Av

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tisha-bav

Is it permissible to learn dikduk of Biblical Hebrew on tish’ah b’av or is it considered learning Torah?

If a grammar or book one is using to learn dikduk quotes pesukim or phrases from תנ״ך to show examples of the grammar rules being discussed is that considered learning Torah and asur on tish’ah b’av?  Since the examples are being used to support the points of grammar and not for the sake of learning Torah per se would this be permissible and not be considered Torah study?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18093/14850

Comment: Related question which I thought you were going to ask: can you learn the Minchas Shai on Eicha?  I suspect no, unless you need it to understand the concepts of the sefer (e.g. lack of dageish in על כן לנידה היתה).

Comment: Do you enjoy it? At some point, if your having a blast then it doesn't really matter if it's on a formal list or not.

Comment: A few years back I asked my Rav if I could practice laining on Tisha B'av, and he said no. My feeling is that dikduk is somewhat parallel to practicing laining.

Comment: @Heshy Isn’t one also allowed to learn all the commentaries on Eicha and other tish’ah b’av permissible material?

Comment: @Salmononius2 See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44197/5275. One is allowed to practice the Tish'a B'Av Torah reading.

Comment: @הבלשן sure if it has to do with tishah be'av.  The Minchas Shai is just about grammar and the proper text.  As I said if you need it to understand the meaning of Eicha that's allowed.  The same would be true if you're doing it to read Eicha properly.  But I'd be very surprised if you can learn the Minchas Shai, even on Eicha, for the purpose of learning grammar.

Comment: @DanF You're right, I meant to say general laining, not Tisha B'av specific laining.